# What's the react hooks equivalent of the following snippet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert the following setState function to React Hooks

```
const setUserAnswer = (answer) => {
     this.setState((state) => ({
       answersCount: {
         ...state.answersCount,
         [answer]: (state.answersCount[answer] || 0) + 1
       },
       answer: answer
     }));
```

Comment: If you dont use `setState` in `Class Compnent`, you can use `useState` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help:

```js
const [answersCount, setAnswersCount] = useState(<default_value>);
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(<default_value>);


const setUserAnswer = (answer) => {
    setAnswersCount(previousState => {
        return {
            ...previousState,
            [answer]: (previousState[answer] || 0) + 1
        }
    })
    
    setAnswer(answer)
}
```